# How to increase the expiration time for new user email activation in JHipster?

Tags: jhipster

I would like to increase the expiration time of the mail sent when a person registers.

I do not see where the expiration time is set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JHipster's register activation email does not have an expiration time, but unactivated accounts are removed after 3 days by default. You can change this timing in [`UserService.java`](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/blob/57ef6172bffa6439bb68e9f397ee85b14de2afc9/src/main/java/io/github/jhipster/sample/service/UserService.java#L266-L280):

```
/**
 * Not activated users should be automatically deleted after 3 days.
 * <p>
 * This is scheduled to get fired everyday, at 01:00 (am).
 */
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 1 * * ?")
public void removeNotActivatedUsers() {
    userRepository
        .findAllByActivatedIsFalseAndActivationKeyIsNotNullAndCreatedDateBefore(Instant.now().minus(3, ChronoUnit.DAYS))
        .forEach(user -> {
            log.debug("Deleting not activated user {}", user.getLogin());
            userRepository.delete(user);
            this.clearUserCaches(user);
        });
}
```